# flex-basis: 0 not respecting parent height in safari

Tags: html, css

below is the code which works on chrome and firefox in which the img respects the parent height and fits into it but in safari, the image overflows.

I can fix this by adding overflow: hidden or removing the flex-basis.

can someone share info on it?

also, it's 2023 and flexbox is almost stable. Is this bug in safari?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.innerChild {
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="innerChild">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/600"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

safari snapshot

[image: safari snapshot]

chrome snapshot

[image: chrome snapshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137085/flexbox-code-working-on-all-browsers-except-safari-why)

Comment: no this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `object-fit: cover;` to your img so it covers the entire width of its parent container:

```
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```